# Python/Flask/SQLAlchemy data in instance list persisting after page reloads

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

##### Project structure

```
app/
-- entrypoint.py
-- database.py
-- models/
---- person.py
---- filtering_class.py
-- pages/
---- routes.py
```

##### Files included in the issues:

###### `entrypoint.py`

```
from flask import Flask
import models

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
```

###### `database.py`

```
from flask import _app_ctx_stack
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///persons.db'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
    connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    bind=engine
)
session = scoped_session(
    SessionLocal,
    scopefunc=_app_ctx_stack.__ident_func__
)

Base = declarative_base()
```

###### `routes.py`

```
from flask import render_template, request
from entrypoint import app
from database import session
from models import Person

@app.route('/person')
def person():
    response_id = request.args.get('id')
    person = session.query(Person).filter_by(id=response_id).first()
    person = Person.get_others(person=person)

    return render_template('person.html',
                        person=person)
```

###### `person.py`

```
from database import Base, session
from models import FilteringClass

class Person(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(80), nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(String(80), nullable=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_persons(filtering_class=None):
        query = session.query(Person.id,
                              Person.first_name,
                              Person.last_name)

        if filtering_class:
            query = filter_class.apply_filters()

        results = query.all()


    @staticmethod
    def get_others(person):
        # Here lies the problem
        filtering_class = FilteringClass()
        # After first call, len(filtering_class.custom_expressions) == 0 (expected), after second call len(...) already == 1, etc
        filtering_class.add_custom_expression(Person.id != person.id)
        return Person.get_persons(filtering_class=filtering_class)
```

###### `filtering_class.py`

```
class FilteringClass(object):

    def __init__(self,
                 custom_expressions=[]):
        self.custom_expressions = custom_expressions

    def apply_filters(self, query):
        # Import Person here to avoid circular import issues in person.py
        from models.person import Person

        if self.custom_expressions:
            for exp in self.custom_expressions:
                query = query.filter(exp)

        return query

    def add_custom_expression(self, expression):
        self.custom_expressions.append(expression)
```

##### Description

FilteringClass is used to filter a passed query argument. It has a method for users of the class to add their own `BinaryExpressions` to be applied when `FilteringClass.apply_filters()` is called.

The goal here is the retrieve all `Person`s that ***are not*** the same as the person who initiated the page request by using the `FilteringClass` to exclude `Person` objects with the same ID.

##### The problem

The expected behavior would be that on each request, a new `FilteringClass` is instantiated (see `Person.get_others` --> `filtering_class = FilteringClass()`).
At that point it is expected that the internal `custom_expressions` array inside `filtering_class` instance would be empty, as defined in its constructor.

However, everytime the page related to the `/person` route is reloaded and the instance of `filtering_class` is created, its `custom_expressions` array is already populated with the previously added custom expression. Meaning that on every page reload, `filtering_class.custom_expressions` will grow without ever coming back to an empty state.

##### What I tried

- Reseting the `custom_expressions` to empty with `self.custom_expressions = []` directly after filtering the passed query.
- Calling `session.close()` right before returning the page template in `/person` endpoint.
- Calling `session.commit()` right before returning the page template in `/person` endpoint (but I don't think I should have to commit anything for a SELECT statement anyways).

Sorry for the long post, I tried to include everything that could be useful (but please let me know if I should add anything).

Comment: It looks like you're hitting [this common issue for new python developers](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

Comment: @larsks Spot on, that was it! Thank you very much, I don't think I would have found that alone. I updated my question with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE: Solution:

As per @larsks ' comment, the issue was **not** related to SQLAlchemy but to a Python gotcha with default mutable arguments (see: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

All there was to do to fix the issue was:

1. Changing `FilteringClass`' constructor from:

```
def __init__(self,
                 custom_expressions=[]):
        self.custom_expressions = custom_expressions
```

to:

```
def __init__(self,
                 custom_expressions=None):
        self.custom_expressions = custom_expressions
```

2. Change the `add_custom_expression` method from:

```
def add_custom_expression(self, expression):
    self.custom_expressions.append(expression)
```

to:

```
def add_custom_expression(self, expression):
    if self.custom_expressions is None:
        self.custom_expressions = []
    self.custom_expressions.append(expression)
```